# java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00001

Tags: java, sql, oracle, primary-key, insert-update

I read hundreds of thousands of lines of text from a text file and insert them into my ORACLE database.

The table has a primary key. I use bulk batch, but it fails because of a unique constraint violation. Unfortunately the text file has duplicate primary-key-data which is not inserting but for updating.

I don't want to use regular insert for poor speed. I store primary-key-data into `array`, change to `update`  when find  duplicate primary-key-data.
is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Please post current code for better understanding of your approach.

Comment: I mean if you post your actual code and data structures it would be easier to understand what's wrong and chances that someone answers your question are higher.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin Sorry for misunderstanding what you mean. Thanks a lot.